# JQuery Datepicker slow loading in table, IE7, JSF App

Tags: jquery, jsf, datepicker

I have a JSF web app, using jQuery datepicker in a table. Table shows list of documentaion, next to each documentation, has date input field which binds to jQuery datepicker via id. If I put jquery script at the very top of the xhtml file, loading is fast.

The problem is, when partial of the table get ajax updated (we using Icefaces 1.8.2), jQuery no longer able to find that date input field id. What I call ajax is we have search function for listed documentation title, once search done, we should show the result list. But is the result list, the calendar dose not show, I think jQuery lost that dynmically generated list input field ids.

So I put the jQuery java script just before the input date field, then things started to work, means after title search, the result list of documetation title showed up along with datepicker.

But the problem is page loading now initail page loading getting so slow, over 30 seconds. Table row is not that many, around 100 something. Below is the xhtml code:

```
   <ice:dataTable var="pItem" value="#{someBackbean.somelist}"
             id="csList"

     <ice:column>
     <ice:panelGrid columns="3">

     <div>

<script type="text/javascript">     
    var jq=jQuery.noConflict();
    jq(document).ready(function(){
    //For id: The $= operator matches the end of the string and the id name mangling is always on the front.
    jq("[id$=fmv]").datepicker({
        showOn: 'button',
        buttonImage: '../../../jquery/images/calendar.gif',
        buttonText: 'Click to select a date', 
        buttonImageOnly: true,  
        duration: 'fast', 
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat:'mm/dd/yy',
        yearRange: '-1:+1',
        showButtonPanel: true,
        closeText: 'Close',
        showWeek: true                      
        })
    });
         </script>

            <ice:inputText id="fmv"
                       size="10"
                       maxlength="10"
                       title="Date of Study"
                       value="#{pItem.dateOfStudy}"
                       validator="#{pItem.validate}"
                       name="fmv"
                       onchange="submit();"                  
                       valueChangeListener="#{pItem.dateChangeListener}"> 
               </ice:inputText>

           </div>  

           <ice:outputText style="color:red;cursor:pointer;"
                           title="Date is required to Print this Form" value="*"/>
           <ice:outputText value="#{pItem.label}" styleClass="nonLink"  />
           <ice:message for="fmv" styleClass="#{pItem.cssClass}" />               
        </ice:panelGrid>
     </ice:column>
  </ice:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are creating the date picker for every row which will be really inefficient. It would be better to create the buttons separately and then delegate a click handler to the table for the buttons (because my guess is you don't need to have more than one date picker at a time). Then you can use one date picker instead of 100. That should speed up the page loading.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, this is business requirement that we have to have a calendar next to each doc, for user to pick. And this app already been runing 4 years. Icefaces1.8.2 calendar just have a bug in IE (not obay z-index), so force me to use other calendar.

Comment: My suggestion is not to remove the datepicker buttons from each row, just to remove the datepicker initialization on each row. Even if you just delayed the init until the button is clicked, it should be faster.

Comment: I see. I will try that idea. Have a command button to invoke datepicker when user click it. Thanks. By the way, Firefox don't have this problem, loading very fast. But IE7 is our company IT only supported browser.

Comment: I used inputText field with onclick event java script. In that java script, associate datapicker to the inputText id. But seems you need 3 or 4 clicks then the calenda will appear. Anybody has other suggetions ? The best way seems still need to put datepicker script at the top of the html file, but need to figure out how to find correct id when partial page updated.

Comment: Finally find a solution. Mainly based on the tip:http://www.vancelucas.com/blog/jquery-ui-datepicker-with-ajax-and-livequery/#comments.